# c++ if (func1() && func2()), does func1 have to be called before func2?

Tags: c++, if-statement

In C++, if I write the following if statement. what's the potential problem? Is the behavior well defined?  Thanks.

```
int i = 0;
// func1 will return the updated value for i.
// func2 will use the new value of i.
if (func1(i) && func2(i)) { ...}
```

Or probably the && can be changed to  ||, is the call still still good?

Comment: If `func2` should use the new value for `i` then `func1` must take a int-reference (`int&`) as input parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, except up to the as-if rule.

`func1() && func2()` means `if (func1()) return true; else return func2()!=false;` roughly (the `return` here isn't a real "return", and it is all one expression, so only roughly).  `func1()?true:func2()` is closer to what it means.

C++ has short-circuit rules.  `&&` evaluates the left hand side first, then if it returns `false` it then evaluates the right hand side.

But, there are always exceptions.

If someone has overridden `&&` for the two arguments, both sides will be evaluated before being passed to `&&`.  This is a good reason to not override `&&`.

Second, the as-if rule means that the compiler is free to evaluate `func2()` if doing so would be as-if you did not do so when `func1()` returned `true`, and if when `func1()` returns `false` it behaves the same as-if it was called 2nd.  Ie, if there is no way that the invocation of `func2()` could be "noticed", *up to undefined behavior*.

An example of that kind of thing would be strict aliasing, where `func1()` changes some value for which there is no defined behavior way for `func2()` to detect it.  But `func2()` through undefined behavior (say, violation of strict aliasing) was expected to detect the change.

If `func2()` has no other interaction with `func1()` provably, and no side effects, then `func2()` can be evaluated before or after `func1()` under the as-if optimization rule.  This might be useful because modern processors can do more than one thing at a time (even in a single "thread" of execution).

Had it *actually* been evaluated after, the result of `func2()` could have been different, but because that dependency depends on undefined behavior the compiler is allowed to time-travel and not have the result you expect be produced.

The long and short of it is that understanding C++ as if it was portable assembly is insufficient.  So while `func1()` must be called before `func2()` logically in the abstract machine that C++ runs on, this does not mean it has to do so on the hardware that your program actually compiles for.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the first operand of `&&` and `||` is always evaluated first.

The second operand is only evaluated if it's needed, according to the value of the first; this is sometimes called *short-circuiting*. For `&&`, it's only called if the first is true; for `||`, only if the first is false.

Answer (score 2):

`func1` will return before `func2` is called. `func2` will not be called if `func1` returns false.

In the case of `||`, `func2` will not be called if `func1` returns true. This is called short-circuiting.